# When writing 'git push' - can I change automatic merge request suggestion to a different branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm using GitLab as the remote repository.

After each `git push` I do, the terminal sends the request and gives me option to create a merge request through the following link:

```
remote: To create a merge request for [branchName], visit:
remote:   [linkToMergeRequest]
```

The problem is that it always tries to make me create a merge request to a specific branch that I don't want to merge into.  (as in I want to create a merge request to branchTwo, but the [linkToMergeRequest] is directing me to create a merge request to branchOne)

Can I change the link direction to direct me to create a merge to branchTwo?

Is it possible?

Comment: "git sends the request and gives me option to create a merge request through the following link" No. Git does not do that. Git has never heard of a "merge request". That message is coming from different software running on the remote, such as GitHub or (here) GitLab. So you are simply asking how the GitLab web site behaves. This is not a Git matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the default branch for your repository:

[image: Repository settings panel]

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't find the actual place in gitlab where you can change the default branch, because I think I did the change locally and I don't have permissions to do it in the remote repository, but from your answer I understood it was about changing the 'default branch' and after that it was really easy to find how to do it localy online, thanks a lot!

Comment: Well! Please accept it if you want.